# R15 Issue on Heroku without exceeding memory limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, paperclip

I have a Ruby on Rails site running on Heroku's performance-M dynamo, with autoscaling set up to 5 dynamos.

Recently, we have been receiving abrupt R15 and H12 errors on the site. During this, memory usage is shown well under the memory quota allowed for the dynamo.

Here are the errors shown in the log:

```
2019-09-16T10:12:08.523336+00:00 app[scheduler.2787]: Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/897302823996a945884a1d912c28d59520190916-4-1bn5w9k.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
2019-09-16T10:12:16.022212+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2787]: Process running mem=1022M(199.7%)
2019-09-16T10:12:16.022295+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2787]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2019-09-16T10:12:16.365725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon-16x16.png" host=www.site.com request_id=8755a947-ace9-471d-a192-a236785505b4 fwd="45.195.5.37" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=928 protocol=https
2019-09-16T10:12:19.103405+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2787]: Process running mem=1279M(250.0%)
2019-09-16T10:12:19.103405+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2787]: Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
2019-09-16T10:12:19.103405+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2787]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-09-16T10:12:19.427029+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2787]: State changed from up to complete
2019-09-16T10:12:19.388039+00:00 heroku[scheduler.2787]: Process exited with status 137
```

```
2019-09-16T10:13:07.886016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.site.com request_id=c7cea0a2-7345-44c6-926e-3ad5a0eb2066 fwd="45.195.5.37" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

As you can see, just before the R15 error, paperclip was trying to compress an image.

The beginning of the graphs in the following screenshots show the status of Heroku Metrics for the affected period:
[Heroku Metrics Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hh2B.png)
[Heroku Metrics Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5CLI.png)

Can anyone please help me figure out how the R15 error, which is related to memory leakage occurring while the metrics show the memory well in the limit? Any help regarding how to stop this situation from repeating will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your R15 error occurred on a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) created by [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler), completely separate from your web dynos. Your request timeouts appear to be unrelated to the memory issues in your scheduled task.

The scheduled task appears to be running on a 1X dyno (`mem=1022M(199.7%)`). To change this, launch the Heroku Scheduler add-on and change the dyno type.

For your request timeouts, check out Scout or New Relic to find the problematic endpoint and where in the stack is taking so long.